# How to set folder icon without icon path?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

So, I have a function that takes a png file and returns icon handle(`IntPtr`). I would like to set folder's icon to the icon I get from that function. I looked through winapi documentation and I found `SHGetSetFolderCustomSettings` function that takes `SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS` structure as an argument. `SHFOLDERCUSTOMSETTINGS` has `pszIconFile` that stores a path to an icon. So the only way to set icon is to give a path to that icon??? Can I use icon handle instead? Or is there a smart way to do it faster rather than just to save my icon as a file and get it's path? The performance really matters. Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Just a guess: put that icon into folder you want to customize and use only icon-name.

Comment: What is folder icon? Are you talking about your software or Windows Explorer?

Comment: _[Possibly relevant...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-create-icon-handlers)_

Comment: The API you discovered requires icons to be backed by the file system, so that they are available even after the producing application is gone. You cannot use that API in combination with a volatile, in-memory resource. MickyD's comment points you to a resource that covers the Shell's Icon Handlers API. This API gives you the freedom you require. Mind you, the Shell hosts many 3rd party extensions, most of which being complete garbage. In an attempt to protect itself, Explorer's extensions run in a separate process. All of that is costly, and you're about to add to your system feeling slow.